# Can not resolve the "XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443"

Tags: apache, xampp

I tried change listen from "httpd.conf" and port from "httpd-ssl.conf". But it  always shows me when I click start   [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2l48.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.

- Simply click on the green check marks to the left of the `Apache` and
  `MySQL` modules to uninstall them.
- Then click the red <kbd>X</kbd>
  to reinstall both modules.
- After that, XAMPP should detect that they are running and everything should work.

Check out my screenshot of the
[XAMPP error log and fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8WVF.png).